# One instance of Report per instance of Simulation: use a singleton?

Tags: java, singleton

I have written code that runs many different simulations, each in its own `Simulation` object. To extract results from a `Simulation`, we first have to ask `Simulation` to create an instance of `Report` (as one of `Simulation`'s children).

Even though a `Simulation` can contain many instances `Report`, the creation process is quite expensive, so if there already is a `Report` in that particular `Simulation`, I want to re-use it rather than create a new one.

The `Report` instances are accessed from many different classes in my code. I'd like to avoid replicating code that first checks whether a `Report` already exists in that particular `Simulation`, then based on that either get the existing one or make a new one.

I really only want there to be one instance of `Report` per `Simulation` -- kind of like a singleton...

I see two avenues:

1. Making a kind of "singleton" report class that allows the creation of no more than one `Report` per `Simulation`. Is this possible?
2. Making a `SpecialSimulation` class that extends `Simulation`, and in `SpecialSimulation` include a singleton that contains a `Report`. Is this overkill?

`Simulation` and `Report` are from a commercial Java API that we have a license for; I can't modify their source code.

Doing my best to learn the ropes of Java and OOP...

Comment: You could initiate the `Report` in the constructor for `SpecialSimulation`, no need for a singleton, then

Comment: Since you can't modify Simulation and Report, and since we don't even have their API doc, it's difficult to answer. However, creating an object in Java is not costly. I suspect that what is costly in generating the report is not to create the object, but to fill it with appropriate values. Reusing the same instance or creating a new one each time new values must be set in the report won't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you really just want to do something like this:

```
public class ReportManager {
    final static ConcurrentMap<Simulation, Report> reports = new ConcurrentHashMap<Simulation, Report>();

    public static Report getReportForSimulation(final Simulation simulation){
        if (!reports.containsKey(simulation)) reports.putIfAbsent(simulation, simulation.getReport());
        return reports.get(simulation);
    }
}
```

Then use the ReportManager to retrieve the Reports. On the positive side, it's very simple, but on the negative side it may theoretically result in a report being generated multiple times in a multithreaded environment, but it would be a rare occurance and you're guaranteed that at least all threads see the exact same Report